Is there a reason that Python allows indexing the class list itself?
I have come across a "feature" of Python that allows one to index the list class (and all classes that implement __getitem__() AFAIK). It took me a non-trivial amount of time to uncover that I wrote brackets instead of parentheses around what I thought was creating a list object.
An example usage:
>>> list[range(10)]  # what I accidentally wrote
list[range(0, 10)]

>>> list(range(10))  # what I meant
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

My question is, why is the former even allowed? Why does it not lead to a runtime error? I realize that this is a functionality of __getitem__() method (as per this question), but my question is more about why is it implemented like this for lists?
Is there a use case where this can be useful?

Further observations
It is also happily accepted as an iterator, leading to:
>>> [l for l in list[range(10)]]
[*list[range(0, 10)]]

I wonder how to interpret this result. It is a one-element list, but the *list[range(0, 10)] is unclear to me. I translate it as a suggestion that we should "unwrap" the elements of the list into the new list.
We get a type error once we try to work with the elements of the list.
>>> [2*l for l in list[range(10)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'types.GenericAlias'

It also gives TypeError when we request the first element of the list:
>>> list[range(10)][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list[range(0, 10)] is not a generic class

But not when we check the existence of an element, which is why I didn't notice the mistake:
>>> 3 in list[range(10)]
False

